# Obtaining a street on Google API Reverse Geocoding V.3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding

The result for Google's Reverse Geocoding API sample[1](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse) provides a street. However when attempting to use similar code for a different lat,lng there is no street. Is parsing results required?

Comment: Can you provide an example that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 0):

At the [very bottom](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#reverse-restricted) of the developers guide there is an answer.

Adjusting "results" from 1 to 0 did the trick.

```
 function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
            var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
            var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
            var latlng = { lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1]) };


            geocoder.geocode({ 'location': latlng }, function (results, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if (results[0]) {
                        map.setZoom(17);
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: latlng,
                            map: map
                        });
                        infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    } else {
                        window.alert('No results found');
                    }
                } else {
                    window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
                }
            });
```